# Error to call Approuter from Postman - SAP CAP (BTP) - *.us10-001.hana.ondemand.com/login/callback redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, sapui5, app-router, sap-cap

I am new to SAP BTP and currently setup a simple project with a **server** and **approuter** on SAP CAP in nodejs. But when querying the approuter url from postman it gives me the following error:

[image]

**Response:**

```
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" />
    <script>
        document.cookie="fragmentAfterLogin="+encodeURIComponent(location.hash)+";path=/";document.cookie="locationAfterLogin="+encodeURIComponent(location.href.split('#')[0].split(location.host)[1])+";path=/";document.cookie="signature=F1rQQvjwRIWe5DinMi%2FLRpgV4G0%3D;path=/";location="https://e517c145trial.authentication.us10.hana.ondemand.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=sb-modeloperativo1!t166096&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fe517c145trial-dev-modelooperativo-approuter.cfapps.us10-001.hana.ondemand.com%2Flogin%2Fcallback"
    </script>
</head>

</html>
```

What I don't understand is that if I open the same url from the browser. Works correctly

**URL:** https://e517c145trial-dev-modelooperativo-approuter.cfapps.us10-001.hana.ondemand.com/odata/v4/catalog/Notificacion

[image]

What's more, if I test the Postman with the url of the server without using the approuter it works fine:

**URL**: https://e517c145trial-dev-modelooperativo-srv.cfapps.us10-001.hana.ondemand.com/odata/v4/catalog/Notificacion

[image]

I have tried trying different configurations, but I can't find the error.

My main project files are the following: https://github.com/franciscobarra/ModeloOperativo/tree/main/ModeloOperativo

**xs-security.json:**

```
{
  "xsappname": "modeloperativo1",
  "tenant-mode": "dedicated",
  "scopes": [
    {  
             "name":"$XSAPPNAME.Callback",
             "description":"With this scope set, the callbacks for subscribe, unsubscribe and getDependencies can be called.",
             "grant-as-authority-to-apps":[  
                "$XSAPPNAME(application,sap-provisioning,tenant-onboarding)"
             ]
        },
    {
        "name": "uaa.user",
        "description": "UAA"
    },
    {
        "name": "$XSAPPNAME.simple-approuter.admin",
        "description": "Simple approuter administrator"
    }
],
  "attributes": [],
  "role-templates": [
    {
      "name": "Token_Exchange",
      "description": "UAA",
      "scope-references": ["uaa.user"]
    },
    {
        "name": "simple-approuter-admin",
        "description": "Simple approuter administrator",
        "scope-references": [
            "$XSAPPNAME.simple-approuter.admin"
        ]
    }
],

"oauth2-configuration": {
  "credential-types": [
    "binding-secret", 
    "x509"
  ],
  "redirect-uris": [
      "https://*.cfapps.us10-001.hana.ondemand.com/**",
      "https://*.applicationstudio.cloud.sap/**",
      "https://*.us10-001.hana.ondemand.com/login/callback"
    ]
  }
}
```

**xs-app.json:**

```
{
    "authenticationMethod": "route",
    "logout": {
        "logoutEndpoint": "/app-logout"
    },
    "routes": [
        {
            "source": "^/user-api(.*)",
            "target": "$1",
            "service": "sap-approuter-userapi"
        },
        {
            "source": "^/(.*)$",
            "target": "$1",
            "destination": "srv-api",
            "csrfProtection": true,
            "authenticationType": "xsuaa"
        }
    ]
    }
```

**mta.yaml:**

```
_schema-version: '3.1'
ID: ModeloOperativo
version: 1.0.0
description: "A simple CAP project."
parameters:
  enable-parallel-deployments: true
build-parameters:
modules:
  - name: ModeloOperativo-srv
    type: nodejs
    path: gen/srv
    parameters:
      buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
    build-parameters:
      builder: npm
    provides:
      - name: srv-api # required by consumers of CAP services (e.g. approuter)
        properties:
          srv-url: ${default-url}
    requires:
      - name: ModeloOperativo-db
      - name: ModeloOperativo-auth
      - name: ModeloOperativo-destination-service
      - name: ModeloOperativo-connectivity-service
      - name: ModeloOperativo-approuter

  - name: ModeloOperativo-db-deployer
    type: hdb
    path: db
    parameters:
      buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
    requires:
      - name: ModeloOperativo-db

  - name: ModeloOperativo-approuter
    properties:
      NODE_DEBUG: 'xssec,passport,http,https'
    type: approuter.nodejs
    path: app/ # from cds.env.folders. Consider also cds.env.build.target -> gen/app
    parameters:
      keep-existing-routes: true
      disk-quota: 256M
      memory: 256M
    requires:
      - name: srv-api
        group: destinations
        properties:
          name: srv-api # must be used in xs-app.json as well
          url: ~{srv-url}
          forwardAuthToken: true
      - name: ModeloOperativo-auth
      - name: ModeloOperativo-srv
      - name: ModeloOperativo-destination-service
      - name: ModeloOperativo-connectivity-service
      - name: ModeloOperativo-logging

resources:
  - name: ModeloOperativo-db
    type: com.sap.xs.hdi-container
    parameters:
      service: hana
      service-plan: hdi-shared
  - name: ModeloOperativo-auth
    type: org.cloudfoundry.managed-service
    parameters:
      service: xsuaa
      service-key:
        name: key-xsuaa
      service-plan: application
      path: ./xs-security.json
      config:
        xsappname: modeloperativo1
        tenant-mode: dedicated
  - name: ModeloOperativo-connectivity-service
    parameters:
      service-plan: lite
      service: connectivity
  - name: ModeloOperativo-destination-service
    parameters:
      service-plan: lite
      service: destination
    type: org.cloudfoundry.managed-service
  - name: ModeloOperativo-uaa-apiaccess
    type: org.cloudfoundry.managed-service
    parameters:
      service: xsuaa
      service-plan: apiaccess
  - name: ModeloOperativo-logging
    type: org.cloudfoundry.managed-service
    parameters:
       service: application-logs
       service-plan: lite
```

**Application: ModeloOperativo-approuter - Service Bindings:**

[image: Application: ModeloOperativo-approuter - Service Bindings]

**RoleCollection - Scopes - User:**

[image]

I would appreciate your help.
Thank you so much